# CSS: self-adjusting table with max width that clips to content width

Tags: css

I am struggling to make the adjustable parent div fit the content:
(I want the widening white space on the right to go away)
http://jsfiddle.net/TDq7T/42/

max-width: and width:fit-content or auto, don't work together

```
#parent {
  display: block;
  max-width:40%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
}

#child {
   display: block;
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
   float:left;
   margin: 10px;
}
```

I tried changing the display modes, clip: auto, width:auto adding another subparent but to no avail :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you used javascript to generate html elements I believe it won't be a problem to style them with javascript (jquery) as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/TDq7T/75/

```
function calculate_m_width() {
    var d_width= $(document).width();
    var m_width= Math.floor((d_width*.4)/70)*70;
    $("#menu").css("width",m_width);
}

calculate_m_width();

window.onresize = function() {
    calculate_m_width();
}
```

each time the browser is resized the width of the menu will be recalculated as number of elemnets x their width (50+2x10)

Comment: and, one more thing: id suppose to be an unique value so child elements shouldn't all have the same id

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thank you so much! :) Is there a way to achieve this with CSS? This isn't too laborious but I would expect CSS to have such a thing:)

Comment: As you noticed by defining max-width the #menu won't stretch fluidly anymore. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex;` on `#menu` (and  erase `float: center`):

http://jsfiddle.net/d3rp294u/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that is what you want, but I will give a try.

```js
var menu = document.createElement('div');
menu.id = 'menu';
document.body.appendChild(menu);



var d = document.createElement('div');
d.id = 'child';
document.body.appendChild(d);

var e = document.createElement('div');
e.id = 'child';
document.body.appendChild(e);

var f = document.createElement('div');
f.id = 'child';
document.body.appendChild(f);

var g = document.createElement('div');
g.id = 'child';
document.body.appendChild(g);

var h = document.createElement('div');
h.id = 'child';
document.body.appendChild(h);



menu.appendChild(d);
menu.appendChild(e);
menu.appendChild(f);
menu.appendChild(g);
menu.appendChild(h);
```

```css
#menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 280px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  float: center;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -moz-justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
#child {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  display:
}
```